# Why can't I see subscript "s" (Unicode Character “ₛ” (U+209B)) even though I can see lots of other unicode characters?

Tags: macos, unicode

So you can copy paste even if you can't see it - subscript "s" (Unicode Character “ₛ” (U+209B))

My main meta question [Should I edit the squares in this title? Is it just me who's seeing them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351276/303080) explains that when I view the site https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+209B

**Question:** I use unicode characters from compart.com and elsewhere frequently (greek letters, arrows, degrees symbol) and I've never had a problem, what is suddenly so challenging about this subscript s?

---

I see this in MacOS 10.11 and Chrome on a late 2012 MacBook Air

[image: ee]

and this in MacOS 10.15 and Safari on a brand new 2020 MacBook Air

[image: ee]

Comment: Seems it's just not included in the default font set at all. Checked macOS 10.14 [web page & full character viewer] & Windows, on which I *can* see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display of any unicode character requires that your machine has a font installed which contains the glyph for it.  Apple doesn't provide fonts for all 130000 unicode characters.  For U+209b you need to download one.  A possible [list](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/209b/fontsupport.htm) is here.

And a font that can be used as a source for installing these glyphs is here: https://dejavu-fonts.github.io

Comment: Yup - confirmed activating Deja Vu now lets me see it.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'm getting the picture now! Seeing "...all 130000 unicode characters" reminds me that we're talking about hundreds of languages and alphabets and symbols and emojis etc. I can see subscript "i" (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D62) but not subscript "s" (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+209B) because someone decided that a subscript "i" was much more universal and so should be included in my computer, but I'd be more likely to need a smily face (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F600) than a subscript "s" :-)

Comment: I have thousands of fonts on this machine, for typesetting etc. Not all are activated at any given time as it can slow the machine to a crawl every time you need to choose a font for anything, so only certain ones are active at any time. I checked Tom's list against what I already had & found Deja Vu was a match…. so I switched it on.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh, *the font* called Deja Vu! Okay got it, thank you!

Comment: I've quoted you [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351293/303080)